# Does sprocket strip comment in .coffee.erb when converting to .js

Tags: ruby, coffeescript, erb, sprockets

It seems # comment in .coffee.erb has been stripped in the final compiled .js

For example:

In https://github.com/marcom-unimelb/unimelb-design-system/blob/master/injection/header/header.coffee.erb

There is a comment like "# IE helper" near the top of file.

https://github.com/marcom-unimelb/unimelb-design-system/blob/master/Rakefile

Following rakefile above, I run `bundle exec rake assets:compile VERSION=0.8`, the final javascript removes hash tag comment. This makes sense, because javascript doesn't support # as starting of comment.

Is there a way to convert # in coffee script to // in javascript or something similar?

Comment: Do you need a `//` comment or will `/* ... */` be sufficient?

Comment: @muistooshort /* ... */ should be enough (or any way to comment). I placed /* */ and compiled it. It gave me error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://coffeescript.org/#strings):

> Sometimes you'd like to pass a block comment through to the generated JavaScript. For example, when you need to embed a licensing header at the top of a file. Block comments, which mirror the syntax for block strings, are preserved in the generated code.

So if you want to get a C-style comment like:

```
/* Pancakes */
```

into your JavaScript, you can use a CoffeeScript block comment:

```
###
Pancakes
###
```

You might also be able to use [back-ticks for embedding](http://coffeescript.org/#embedded) JavaScript inside CoffeeScript but that tends to give you unwanted semicolons. For example,

```
`// Pancakes`
```

in your CoffeeScript becomes:

```
// Pancakes;
```

in your JavaScript.

I'd lean towards block comments since (a) that's what they're for and (b) back ticks are a bit of an ugly hack.

BTW, it isn't Sprockets that is eating your CoffeeScript comments, that is CoffeeScript itself.

Comment: I am using vim with vim-coffee-script plugin. For a single #, I can precede tab or spaces. With ###, I need to precede with spaces only, otherwise it gave me indent syntax error. Is this normal?

Comment: You need to pick either spaces xor tabs for indentation with CoffeeScript, mixing them causes all sorts of confusion.